# MATLAB vectorization: filling struct fields from vector elements

Tags: matlab, vector, struct, vectorization

I have a vector of structs each having a field `x`:

```
s1.x = 1;
s2.x = 2;
s3.x = 3;
S = [s1, s2, s3];
```

I would like to set the field `x` of all structs in `S` from a given vector `X`, i.e. I would like to vectorize the following loop:

```
X = [97, 98, 99];
for i = 1 : length(S)
    S(i).x = X(i);
end
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
Xc = num2cell(X); %// convert X to cell array of numbers
[S.x] = Xc{:}; %// generate comma-separated list from cell array, and assign
```

For Matlab versions before 7.0 the second line [should be changed](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) into

```
[S.x] = deal(Xc{:}); %// generate comma-separated list from cell array, and assign
```

Comment: Great, that does it! Could you please explain why this works and `[S.x] = X` doesn't? Sometimes this vectorization stuff seems a little bit like voodoo to me.

Comment: You can omit the `deal` if we're dealing with cell arrays, so just do it like: `[S.x] = Xc{:};`

Comment: @MGA: X is a vector and `Xc{:}` is a comma-separated list. Simply converting to another data structure in between to get it done. @Luis Mendo: `deal` could be removed to get an even shorter solution.

Comment: @rayryeng I'm too old-style with `deal` I guess... Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for providing the explanation

Comment: @LuisMendo - lol no problem.  Mind you for everything else, you would need the `deal`, but with cell arrays you can omit it.  I figured it may save some clock cycles, but the `deal` is certainly more explicit!

Comment: The answer above did not work for me. In this way it does work: `Xc = num2cell(X);` 
`[S.x(1:length(Xc))] = Xc{:};`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the values in advance, you can initialize like this:

```
S = struct('x', {1 2 3})
```

Comment: Good tip, but that's not what I'm after. `S` already exists, and I want to replace all the `x` fields at once from the vector `X`.